# Service bus: Fixing general Error on Send Message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am just getting started with the service bus. I created a bus and created a queue.

I am using the following C# console code to get started. When I run this, I receive a general error. What am I missing? How do I troubleshoot this?

From the docs, I checked the connection by going to the URL and checking the ports on PowerShell. I am using the Primary connection string and the queue name and Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus nuget package.
I went into the queue on Azure portal and tried sending a message. I got this error [image]

Error I am getting:

> The service was unable to process the request; please retry the
> operation. For more information on exception types and proper
> exception handling, please refer to
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101
> TrackingId:378674341cb049f8b1415dd6e5fb5fd4_G15,
> SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2023-09-16T14:37:25 (GeneralError).
> For troubleshooting information, see
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot.

[image: code]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The tracking ID you get there, this is something you could use with Azure support to understand why ASB service is throwing. Alternatively, try a different entity to rule out a rouge deployment.

Comment: You may find some more information when logging Azure SDK requests (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging)

Comment: That's a service-generated error, not something from the client.  Unfortunately, that means capturing client logs won't help.  From the error, it doesn't appear to be related to auth, but looks more like a potential issue with the node hosting the resource.  I'd suggest opening a support case with the tracking, as Sean mentioned.  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2202692&clcid=0x409